# How to retrieve all list items from all site collections under a SharePoint tenant using Search Api

Tags: sharepoint-search, search-api

I need to fetch all list items with the conditions as

1. The item could be of any content type (OOB content types or custom content types).
2. The item could be in any site collection under my SharePoint Domain/Tenant.
3. The item fields are not fixed as they can be of any content type
4. and lastly I want to filter these items on the basis of the items liked by current user.

So Firstly I need to know the search api url to get all items and then the additional filter part to fetch only liked items.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/089481d1-eb20-4fdf-972e-9ec392e79344/what-is-the-rest-endpoint-url-to-get-list-of-site-collections-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointdevelopment Take a look at this thread, it has explained answer in it.

Comment: The Link doesn't help much it explains how to get all webs or sites across different site collections but not items.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/ Here, it does have different type of result type options. What you are looking is `ContentClass:STS_ListItem`